# Using background-position with background-repeat for a CSS sprite

Tags: css, css-sprites, sprite

[Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/rx3NU/), and here is the sprite:

[image: sprite]

I want to use the arrow in a markup, like this:

```
<div class="tooltip">
    The tooltip
    <span class="arrow"></span>
</div>
```

Setting:

```
background-image: url(foobar.gif);
background-position: 0 -40px;
background-repeat: none;
```

does not seem to work (as expected). Any workaround?

Comment: How is the span.arrow getting a height and width? As your code stands, because it is an empty inline element, it won't have any dimensions and you won't see the background image.

Comment: @Andy: I've set up the demo. I'd rather not set a width on the span because I need a top border on the span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

`background-repeat:no-repeat` ?

Comment: That was mighty silly of me. I've updated the fiddle and it even works on IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Use height and width exactly..

for example,

```
background-position: 0 -40px; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height:32px;
width:32px;
```

or use the sprites generators online and they will render both images and css..

eg: http://spritegen.website-performance.org/

Answer (score 0):

hm try this:

```
background: url(foobar.gif) 0 -40px no-repeat transparent;
```

should be work.